# Netbeans NullpointerException at startup

Tags: macos, netbeans, nullpointerexception

When I start Netbeans 6.0.1 up, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:521)
    at com.sun.servicetag.RegistrationDocument.initializeDocument(RegistrationDocument.java:121)
    at com.sun.servicetag.RegistrationDocument.load(RegistrationDocument.java:81)
    at com.sun.servicetag.RegistrationData.loadFromXML(RegistrationData.java:392)
    at org.netbeans.modules.reglib.NbServiceTagSupport.getRegistrationData(NbServiceTagSupport.java:373)
    at org.netbeans.modules.reglib.NbServiceTagSupport.getNbServiceTag(NbServiceTagSupport.java:453)
    at org.netbeans.modules.reglib.NbServiceTagSupport.createNbServiceTag(NbServiceTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.netbeans.modules.registration.NbInstaller.restored(NbInstaller.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.loadCode(NbInstaller.java:378)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.load(NbInstaller.java:297)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:933)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:405)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:341)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:275)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:171)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:110)
[catch] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:655)
```

It doesn't keep Netbeans from functioning, I think, but what does it mean and how should I fix it?

Comment: What does your messages.log file say?

Comment: It says the same thing. Except there's even another NullPointerException following this one. I'll try upgrading to 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would try a newer version of netbeans. 6.0.1 is well over 5 years old.

Also, try clearing out the netbeans cache. On linux, it's stored at $HOME/.netbeans/
Not sure where it would be stored on OSX.

As for what it means - read over this question/answer: [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I know what a NullPointerException is, I'm referring to this one specifically. Will it cause trouble with any Netbeans funtionalities if I don't fix it?

Comment: It was an issue with 6.0.1, but was fixed starting with 6.1
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=167808

There's no guarantees of what it will do, so I would suggest upgrading your netbeans version.